# Combining input and select into one visible input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I am new to styling html elements (e.g. input & select in this case), and I am looking to implement a visually combined input / select element.  In essence the input and select would still be completely separate as form elements, but based on class and css I would like to inset the contents of the select menu into the right hand side of the input field.  Sorry I am no photoshoper, so here is a representation of what it might look like:

```
 ------------------------------------------------
 |                              Select text [v] |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see the left hand portion of the input is where you would type the string for the input element, and the select drop down is inset into the border of the input element (the [v] is supposed to be a down arrow button to drop the list).  Any links to how to get stared styling something like this or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So basically a text box you can type into and get a list of matching possibilities from a dropdown?

Comment: if its what marc b is describing you might want to just use a datalist

Comment: @Marc, not really.  I want to have an input, and a drop down.  The drop down would be search terms like "customers, contacts, phone numbers", and the input text would relate to whatever search term you are selecting.  I could just put an input on the screen, then a drop down next to it and accomplish the same thing, but I want to inset the select menu into the select border because I think it would look really slick.

Answer (score 7):

The following example is very simple. It shows the main thing you would want to do: Since form elements are able to be styled with CSS just as everything else, it is pretty straightforward. This example still has some styling issues with non-firefox browsers, I will improve it a little.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        select#selectoption {
            border-left:none;
            padding:none;
        }

        input#datahere {
            position:relative;
            border-right:none;
            padding:none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    The form below is a simple example.
<form name ="explanation"action="test" method="post">
<input type="text" id="datahere" />
<select id="selectoption" /><option>test</option><option>test2</option></select>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: An online example of what you want can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/xFQMf/3/

Answer (score 7):

The [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element might help
(Safari doesn't support this, yet).

Comment: Did not know this one. You saved me a couple hours of styling.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="city" list="cityname">
<datalist id="cityname">
    <option value="Blida">
    <option value="OuledSlama">
</datalist>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30390522)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30390522)

Comment: How is that a comment/question. Seems like an attempt to answer to me... If you think it is not a *good* answer - feel free to downvote. Indeed code-only answers are not considered useful, but we don't delete them... @HedayatullahSarwary

Comment: @NotABot see above

Answer (score 0):

use [ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select)
with the `[addTag]` set to true.

Hope it helps someone :)